# Selecting randomly from two arrays based upon condition in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

Suppose i have two arrays of equal lengths:

```
a = [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1]
b = [0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0]
```

Now i want to pick up elements from these two arrays , in the sequence given such that they form a new array of same length as a & b  by randomly selecting values between a & b, in the ratio of a:b = 4.68 i.e for every 1 value picked from a , there should be 4.68 values picked from b in the resultant array.

So effectively the resultant array could be something like  :

```
res = [0,1,1,0,1, 1(from a) ,0(from a),1,1,0,0,1,1,0, 0(from a),0,0]
```

res array has : first 5 values are from b ,6th & 7th from a ,8th-14th from b , 15th from a ,16th-17th from b

Overall ratio of values from a:b in the given res array example is a:b 4.67 ( from a = 3 ,from b = 14 )

Thus between the two arrays, values have to be chosen at random however the sequence needs to be maintained i.e cannot take 7th value from one array and 3rd value from other .If the value to be populated in resultant array is 3rd then the choice is between the 3rd element of both input arrays at random.Also, overall ratio needs to be maintained as well.

Can you please help me in developing an efficient Pythonic way of reaching this resultant solution ? The solution need not be consistent with every run w.r.t values

Comment: Can you use numpy?

Comment: Does the ratio have to be as close to exact as possible, or is it just a probability?

Comment: Can use numpy . Ratio needs to be as close to second decimal point as possible

Comment: @raul: So just to be clear, selections aren't independent? If, by chance, the first three values from `a` were chosen for the first three values from `res`, then all other values in `res` *must* come from `b`, correct?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes precisely

Comment: Why has been the question voted down ? I believe i was clear in the problem statement and it isn't irrelevant !! huh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing the `a_count` calculation from [Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54677296/364696) (because it seems to work and I can't be bothered to reinvent it), this solution preserves the ordering of the values chosen from `a` and `b`:

```
from future_builtins import zip  # Only on Python 2, to avoid temporary list of tuples
import random

# int() unnecessary on Python 3
a_count = int(round(1/(1 + 4.68) * len(a)))

# Use range on Python 3, xrange on Python 2, to avoid making actual list
a_indices = frozenset(random.sample(xrange(len(a)), a_count))

res = [aval if i in a_indices else bval for i, (aval, bval) in enumerate(zip(a, b))]
```

The basic idea here is that you determine how many `a` values you need, get a unique sample of the possible indices of that size, then iterate `a` and `b` in parallel, keeping the `a` value for the selected indices, and the `b` value for all others.

If you don't like the complexity of the `list` comprehension, you could use a different approach, copying `b`, then filling in the `a` values one by one:

```
res = b[:]  # Copy b in its entirety

# Replace selected indices with a values
# No need to convert to frozenset for efficiency here, and it's clean
# enough to just iterate the sample directly without storing it
for i in random.sample(xrange(len(a)), a_count):
    res[i] = a[i]
```

Comment: Getting this TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: @raul: Yeah, I forgot this was for Python 2. Just needs an `int` conversion (already edited in), because `round` on Python 2 always returns `float` (on Python 3, it returns `float` only when passed a second argument, and `int` for a single argument). Side-note: [Python 2 reaches end-of-life in less than a year](https://devguide.python.org/#status-of-python-branches). New code should really target Python 3.

Comment: brilliant you are.Thanks to you as well as Barmar .This is an ensembling model that i'm developing based on distance weights and you guys gave an exquisite way to compute it

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work. You specify how many you want from a (you can simply use your ratio to figure out that number), you randomly generate a 'mask' of numbers and choose from a or be based on the cutoff (notice that you only sort to figure out the cutoff, but you use the unsorted mask later)

```
import numpy as np

a = [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1]
b = [0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0]

mask = np.random.random(len(a))
from_a = 3
cutoff = np.sort(mask)[from_a]

res = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    if (mask[i]>=cutoff):
        res.append(a[i])
    else:
        res.append(b[i])
```